# SceneKit Scene timeoffset not working

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to replicate the WWDC 2013 skinning.m slide but I am having trouble with the timeOffset function on the CCAnimationGroup. When I implement the timeoffset in my code it dos not offset the time as it does in apples code it simply just starts from the beginning of my animation no matter what I do.

What is the difference between what apple has done an what i have done?

here is a snippet of apples code:

```
- (void)extractAnimationsFromSceneSource:(SCNSceneSource *)sceneSource
{


// In this scene objects are animated separately using long animations
// playing 3 successive animations. We will group these long animations
// and then split the group in 3 different animation groups.
// We could also have used three DAEs (one per animation).

NSArray *animationIDs = [sceneSource identifiersOfEntriesWithClass:[CAAnimation class]];

NSUInteger animationCount = [animationIDs count];
NSMutableArray *longAnimations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:animationCount];

CFTimeInterval maxDuration = 0;

for (NSInteger index = 0; index < animationCount; index++) {
    CAAnimation *animation = [sceneSource entryWithIdentifier:animationIDs[index] withClass:[CAAnimation class]];
    if (animation) {
        maxDuration = MAX(maxDuration, animation.duration);
        [longAnimations addObject:animation];
     //   NSLog(@"%@",[longAnimations description]);
    }
}

CAAnimationGroup *longAnimationsGroup = [[CAAnimationGroup alloc] init];
longAnimationsGroup.animations = longAnimations;
longAnimationsGroup.duration = maxDuration;

CAAnimationGroup *idleAnimationGroup = [longAnimationsGroup copy];
idleAnimationGroup.timeOffset = 6.45833333333333;
_idleAnimationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
_idleAnimationGroup.animations = @[idleAnimationGroup];
_idleAnimationGroup.duration = 24.71 - 6.45833333333333;
_idleAnimationGroup.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
_idleAnimationGroup.autoreverses = YES;
```

}

and here is my code in swift:

init the animation in the class :

```
class myViewController: UIViewController,
var _idleAnimationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()

...

  func extractAnimationsFromSceneSource(sceneSource: SCNSceneSource)

    {

    var animationsIDs = sceneSource.identifiersOfEntriesWithClass(CAAnimation.self) as [String]

    var animationCount = animationsIDs.count

    var longAnimations:[CAAnimation] = []
    var maxDuration : CFTimeInterval = 0;

    for animationID in animationsIDs {
        if let animation = sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier(animationID, withClass: CAAnimation.self) as? CAAnimation {
            var maxDuration = max(maxDuration, animation.duration);
          longAnimations.append(animation)
        }

    }

        var longAnimationsGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        longAnimationsGroup.animations = longAnimations
        longAnimationsGroup.duration = maxDuration

        var idleAnimationGroup :CAAnimationGroup = longAnimationsGroup.copy() as CAAnimationGroup

        idleAnimationGroup.timeOffset = 2.5

        _idleAnimationGroup.animations = [idleAnimationGroup]
        _idleAnimationGroup.duration = 1.0


}
```

No matter how I chnage the timeoffset it always starts at 0. I see that apple has copied an animation group with a time offset and then used that to instantiate a new animation group based on that offset. I have tried to do this in my code as you can see but it does not change anything!!

Al I can thinkof at the moment is that the timeoffset property is not supported by iOS?? maybe its only supported by cocoa??

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: it seems that `maxDuration` is re-declared in the for loop, so in the end `maxDuration` will still be 0

Comment: i cant thank you enough !!! that fixed my problem. i have been pulling my hair out for days!!